# Is There a Way to Decode an AES Key from Base64 to UTF-8 String?

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I am generating an AES-256 SecretKey using:

```
            KeyGenerator aesKeyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            aesKeyGen.init(256);
            SecretKey secretKey = aesKeyGen.generateKey();
            clientAesKey = secretKey.getEncoded();
```

Is there a way that I can see the array of bytes as a string? Only way that works for me is this:

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(clientAesKey);
```

If I print it and copy the string, and try to decode it using an online Base64 decoder, it complains that the string is not UTF-8.

I know it defeats the purpose of encryptions, but is there a way that I can assign a static 32-characters long string  as a secret key?

Comment: In most scenarios where you want to "view" or "eyeball" a key you probably want to look at its hex encoding. Trying to view it as a UTF-8 string makes little sense unless you know or suspect that the bytes of the key are actually directly encoded from characters. What do you hope to achieve by "viewing" an AES key?

Comment: The backend that is decrypting my encryption have given me static AES and IV. I was hoping to figure out a way that I can hardcode the values for encryption to see that we both get the same values encrypted for same given inputs. But I assume that I can simply just set an array of bytes of length 32 to static values and pass it as my key? Instead of trying to figure out a way to hardcode a string as a key.
Also, thank you for all your answers, I have been seeing them all around encryption posts and you have been of great help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to 'visualize' a key:

```
System.out.println(new java.math.BigInteger(1, keyBytes).toString(16));
```